# How to use subjunctive mood

Tags: usage

What is the difference between the following two sentences

> I would die before I **lied**
>
> I would die before I **lie**

Is the first one in subjunctive mood?

Answer (score 2):

> *I would die before I lied*.
>
> *I would die before I lie.*

No: subjunctive clauses are headed by a plain form of the verb, e.g. "I insisted [that he **meet** her]". But "lied" is past tense so it can't be subjunctive.

In any case, only a very few prepositions, like "if", "unless", "lest" etc. license subjunctives, so neither of your examples qualify.